# Get notification when exiting from the beacons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, beacon

I am working with three iBeacons to find its range on iPhone/ iPad for attendance procedure. I need the three beacons should be identifiable by the app and when the user enter into any one beacon's region they should get a notification that they are logged in. And it should only logged out when the user exit from all the three beacons.

At the same time the user should not get any notification if the user is already logged in or when he enters into a new beacon.(Means user changed his position from one beacon to another beacon's region).

Here in my code the three beacons are identified and getting logged in notification. But it is not getting logged out when exiting the three beacons and getting logged out when inside the region and changed to one beacon to another.

Please help me anyone to solve my problem.

Here is my Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [parameters setObject:EmpID.text forKey:@"eid"];
    [parameters setObject:@"entry" forKey:@"type"];

    NSLog(@"Params:%@",parameters);

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *sermanager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    sermanager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    sermanager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-application-id-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-rest-api-key-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
    [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    sermanager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;


    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://livmob.com/beacon/index.php/api/Employee/getEmployeeDetails"];

    [sermanager POST:urlString parameters:parameters  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSError *error = nil;
         NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
         NSLog(@"JSON:%@",JSON);

         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         NSString *empIdGet=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.eid"][0];
         NSArray *bloodGroup=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.bloodGroup"][0];
         NSArray *department=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.department"][0];
         NSArray *dob=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.dob"][0];
         NSArray *email=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.email"][0];
         NSArray *name=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.name"][0];
         NSArray *phone=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.phone"][0];
         NSArray *photo=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.photo"][0];
         NSArray *role=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"Response.employeeDetail.role"][0];

         empid=empIdGet;

         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:empIdGet forKey:@"EMPID"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:role forKey:@"EMP_ROLE"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:photo forKey:@"EMP_PHOTO"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:phone forKey:@"EMP_PHONE"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:name forKey:@"EMP_NAME"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:email forKey:@"EMP_EMAIL"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dob forKey:@"EMP_DOB"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:department forKey:@"EMP_DEPT"];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:bloodGroup forKey:@"EMP_BLOOD"];


         NSUUID * nearUUID =[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"]];

         self.beaconRegion =[[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:nearUUID identifier:@"near"];
         [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
         [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
         UUIDStr = [nearUUID UUIDString];

         NSUUID *nearUUID1 =[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"6CA02DDF-78A2-3F7E-DD54-238F91B19E57"]];

         self.beaconRegion1 =[[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:nearUUID1 identifier:@"near"];

         [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion1];
         [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion1];
         UUIDStr1 = [nearUUID1 UUIDString];

NSUUID *nearUUID2 =[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DD5D08FD-303F-4B8B-D8FB-89D491955B2E"]];

         self.beaconRegion1 =[[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:nearUUID2 identifier:@"near"];

         [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion1];
         [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion1];
         UUIDStr2 = [nearUUID2 UUIDString]; 

         [self entryMethod];

         self.proximityContentManager = [[ProximityContentManager alloc]
                                         initWithBeaconIDs:@[
                                                             [[BeaconID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"6CA02DDF-78A2-3F7E-DD54-238F91B19E57" major:41073 minor:64330],
                                                             [[BeaconID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D" major:590 minor:16462],
                                                             [[BeaconID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"DD5D08FD-303F-4B8B-D8FB-89D491955B2E" major:41749 minor:53281]
                                                             ]
                                         beaconContentFactory:[[CachingContentFactory alloc] initWithBeaconContentFactory:[BeaconDetailsCloudFactory new]]];
         self.proximityContentManager.delegate = self;

         [self.proximityContentManager startContentUpdates];

     }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {

         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

         NSLog(@"Error:%@",error.localizedDescription);
     }];

    }
return YES;
}

- (void)proximityContentManager:(ProximityContentManager *)proximityContentManager didUpdateContent:(id)content
{

BeaconDetails *beaconDetails = content;
if (beaconDetails)
{
    NSLog(@"beaconDetails %@",beaconDetails.beaconName);
    beaconNameStr = beaconDetails.beaconName;
}
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
           inRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

NSLog(@"Own Beacons %@",beacons);

self.beaconsArray = beacons;


for (CLBeacon *beacon in self.beaconsArray)
{
    if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate)
    {
        NSLog(@"Own State Immediate %@",beaconNameStr);
    }
    else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)
    {
        NSLog(@"Own State Near %@",beaconNameStr);
    }
    else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar)
    {
        NSLog(@"Own State Far %@",beaconNameStr);
    }
    else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Own State Unknown %@",beaconNameStr);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Own Exited %@",beaconNameStr);


    }
}
}


-(void)entryMethod
{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"Already entered" forKey:@"userstatus"];

NSString *statusStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userstatus"]];

if ([statusStr isEqualToString:@"Already entered"])
{

[defaults synchronize];
NSString *empIdNew =[defaults objectForKey:@"EMPID"];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[parameters setObject:empIdNew forKey:@"eid"];
[parameters setObject:@"entry" forKey:@"type"];

NSLog(@"Params:%@",parameters);


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *sermanager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
sermanager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
sermanager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-application-id-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
[sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-rest-api-key-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
[sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
sermanager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://livmob.com/beacon/index.php/api/Employee/employeeLogin"];

[sermanager POST:urlString parameters:parameters  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSError *error = nil;
     NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
     NSLog(@"JSON:%@",JSON);

 }


         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error");
 }];


NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults1 synchronize];
[defaults1 setValue:@"You are Time In" forKey:@"defaultStatus"];

SeconVC *second = (SeconVC *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SeconVC"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}

else {
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
notification.alertBody = @"You are Time In!";
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}}
//*******************************didEnterRegion:***************************************//

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    [self.proximityContentManager startContentUpdates];

    NSLog(@"Emp ID:%@",empid);

    NSString *statusStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userstatus"]];

    if (![statusStr isEqualToString:@"Already entered"])
    {


        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(PerformingDelay)
                                           object:nil];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [defaults setObject:@"Already entered" forKey:@"userstatus"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        NSString *empIdNew =[defaults objectForKey:@"EMPID"];

            if ([UUIDStr isEqualToString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"] || [UUIDStr1 isEqualToString:@"6CA02DDF-78A2-3F7E-DD54-238F91B19E57"])
            {
                NSLog(@"you are Login into %@",beaconNameStr);

                NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [parameters setObject:empIdNew forKey:@"eid"];
                [parameters setObject:@"entry" forKey:@"type"];

                NSLog(@"Params:%@",parameters);

                if (empid.length ==0)
                {
                    NSLog(@"No values are passed");
                }
                else
                {
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:statusStrNew forKey:@"EMPID"];


                    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [defaults1 synchronize];
                    [defaults1 setValue:@"You are Time In" forKey:@"defaultStatus"];

                    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                    SeconVC *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SeconVC"];

                    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                    notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
                    notification.alertBody = @"You are Time In!";
                    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

                    if (timeStr.length ==0) {
                        NSLog(@"No values passed");
                    }
                    else{
                        NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                        [parameters setObject:timeStr forKey:@"logoutTime"];

                    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *sermanager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
                    sermanager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
                    sermanager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
                    [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-application-id-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
                    [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-rest-api-key-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
                    [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                    sermanager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

                    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://livmob.com/beacon/index.php/api/Employee/employeeLogin"];

                    [sermanager POST:urlString parameters:parameters  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                     {
                         NSError *error = nil;
                         NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                         NSLog(@"JSON:%@",JSON);

                     }
                             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"Error");


                     }];
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    }

//*******************************Exit Functions****************//
-(void)PerformingDelay
{

        NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults1 synchronize];
        [defaults1 setValue:@"You are Time Out" forKey:@"defaultStatus"];

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        notification.alertBody = @"You are Time Out!";
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"You Left!"
                                                             forKey:@"Notify"];
        notification.userInfo = userDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];


        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults synchronize];
        NSString *empId =[defaults objectForKey:@"EMPID"];
        [defaults setObject:@"User Left" forKey:@"userstatus"];

        if (empId.length ==0)
        {
            NSLog(@"No values are passed");
        }
        else
        {

            @try
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [parameters setObject:empId forKey:@"eid"];
                [parameters setObject:@"exit" forKey:@"type"];

                NSLog(@"Params:%@",parameters);


                NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
                if (internetStatus == NotReachable)
                {

                    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

                    notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];

                    notification.alertBody = @"Internet connection is lost, your attendance status will not be updated. Please check your internet connection to update it.";

                    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

                    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

                    timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
                    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

                    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:timeStr];

                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date forKey:@"logoutTime"];

                }
                else
                {

                AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *sermanager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
                sermanager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
                sermanager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
                [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-application-id-removed"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
                [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"parse-rest-api-key-removed" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];
                [sermanager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                sermanager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

                NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://livmob.com/beacon/index.php/api/Employee/employeeLogin"];

                [sermanager POST:urlString parameters:parameters  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                 {
                     NSError *error = nil;
                     NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                     NSLog(@"JSON:%@",JSON);

                 }
                         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error");
                 }];
                            }
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception)
            {
                NSLog(@"Emp Id Error");
            }
        }
    }



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{

[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    [self performSelector:@selector(PerformingDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:120.0];
    NSLog(@"User Logged Out %@", beaconNameStr);

    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults1 synchronize];
    [defaults1 setValue:@"You are Time Out" forKey:@"defaultStatus"];
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: That's 423 lines of code. You'll greatly increase the chance of getting help if you trim it down, focusing more on the "Minimal" in "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is too much for me to read. I do not really go through it.

You have 3 UUID for 3 beacons(regions).
With each enter/exit, iOS will have a callback didEnterRegion and didExitRegion independently.

What you need to do is use a variable to record 3 regions status, in or out.
And then you check status in each didEnterRegion/didExitRegion callback and have rule as below:

didEnterRegion:

if 0 in changes to 1 in : user first enter the region

didExitRegion

if x in changes to 0 in ( x != 0): user first completely exit the region

Hope this help you.

Comment: Sorry as i was new to it (posting questions), will make it here after.  Any way thanks for your Answer. it worked out for me. and sorry for late reply.